# String of jinja2 python > Json

Tags: python, json, string, jinja2

I Must set variables in json so... i trying to do

```
{{ {{ config['port'] }} * ({{ channel_id }} * 100) - 100 }}
```

but doesn't work

Someone help me ?

Comment: What? Could you give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

Just use one pair of {{ }} brackets:

```
{{ config['port'] * (channel_id * 100) - 100 }}
```

The brackets tell jinja "Insert this computed expression here".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short sample demonstrating how to create a JSON string from a template. Note particularly the complex math expression inside a single set of `{{ }}` brackets.

```
# First, let's create JSON from a template
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('''
    { "port_addr_{{channel_id}}" :
        {{ (config['port'] * channel_id * 100 ) - 100 }}
    }''')
jstring = template.render(channel_id=7, config={'port':5})

# Now test to confirm it's valid
import json
pdict = json.loads(jstring)
assert pdict['port_addr_7'] == 3400
```

Answer (score 0):

probably have to escape it with `safe`, something like:

```
{{json_stuff | safe}}
```

Comment: Not necessarily true, it depends on how the data is produced. But the OP is nesting Jinja2 brackets, there is no need for that.